# "Abandoned" Ubercart orders marked as "completed" in CiviCRM

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, ubercart

I'm using Drupal (7.38), CiviCRM (4.6.5), Ubercart (7.x-3.8) and Ubercart_CiviCRM (7.x-4.x-dev). Whenever a user (registered/anonymous) purchases a product from the site, a contribution will be added into the CivCRM contact. If the user is anonymous, the system will create a user in Drupal as well as a contact in CiviCRM, linked by the email address. I notice some of the orders have a status of 'Abandoned' in Ubercart, but under CiviCRM's contribution tab for this contact, it is listed as 'Completed'.

I have gone through the `uc_civicrm` module and I found the following code in uc_civicrm/uc_civicrm.module

```
function _uc_civicrm_map_contribution_status($order_status) {
  // NOTE: There may be a more "correct" way to do this.
  $map = array(
    "completed"        => 1,
    "payment_received" => 1,
    "pending"          => 2,
    "processing"       => 5,
    "canceled"         => 3,
    "in_checkout"      => 5,
  );

  if (array_key_exists($order_status, $map)) {
    $id = $map[$order_status];
  }
  else {
    // Oh no.
    $id = 1;
    watchdog('uc_civicrm', 'There is no status that maps to %order_status, marking as "Complete"', array('%order_status' => $order_status), WATCHDOG_WARNING);
  }

  return $id;
}
```

I want to synchronize Ubercart's order status with the CiviCRM contribution status. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map 'abandoned' to the 'canceled' status in CiviCRM (there is no "abandoned" status in CiviCRM) you could revise the above like so:

```
$map = array(
 "completed"        => 1,
 "payment_received" => 1,
 "pending"          => 2,
 "processing"       => 5,
 "canceled"         => 3,
 "abandoned"         => 3,
 "in_checkout"      => 5,
);
```

Then I'd recommend making a bug report/patch [on the issue you filed at the project page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2606644) so it gets into the module core if the maintainers agree.